# How to only render 25 objects to the screen at a time even though I am mapping over an array containing 1,000 objects using React.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux.

In one of my components, I want to map over an array that contains 1000 objects, but only render 25 at a time to the screen.

It would also be ideal to have a button that says "load more" which renders another 25 when a user clicks it.

In my Redux state, I don't mind if there is an array containing 1,000 objects so I don't want to limit the results returned from the database or anything. I just want to control the render method.

Here is my renderProducts() method which I call inside of the my component's main render method:

```
renderProducts() {

      return this.props.allProducts.map(product => {
        return (
          <div key={product._id} className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" id="productThumbnail">
            <SingleProduct
               key={product._id}
               product={product} />
          </div>
         );
      });
}
```

this.props.allProducts is an array that contains the 1,000 objects. How can I only render 25 at a time and implement a function for a button that will increment the number on the screen by 25 at each time?

Comment: Add a slice call before map and pass pagination params to it.

Comment: Like this? this.props.allProducts.slice(0,26).map({}); And if I wanted to add the pagination param would the params value need to be a string? Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? This function is a generic one, you pass an array of products you have in your redux state, current page and pageSize, which is how many items are per page. You will need to add UI and extend store to keep track of page and pageSize in the state as well I assume. So eventually they will be available through `this.props` in your component just like `this.props.allProducts` are available.

```
renderProducts(allProducts = [], page, pageSize) {
    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
    const endIndex = Math.min(page * pageSize + pageSize, allProducts.length);

    const viewProducts = allProducts.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

      return viewProducts.map(product =>
        <div
          key={product._id}
          className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"
          id="productThumbnail"
        >
          <SingleProduct
            key={product._id}
            product={product}
          />
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: What are the values of page and pageSize? How do they get their values?

Comment: I updated my reply. Added a comment to give you an idea on how to implement this. Implementation is not so trivial to write it all in full in StackOverflow but you can get the main idea and implement it yourself. Just extend the redux store to support page and pageSize and then add UI which will allow changes for those variables.